# LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class `ieeeconf', but the document class provides `cssconf'

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I am having a problem when trying to compile my .tex document, where I get the following output:

```
TraditionalBuilder: Invoking latexmk... done.

No errors. Warnings:

./ieeeconf.cls: LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class `ieeeconf', but the document class provides `cssconf'.

[Done!]
```

The document compiles nicely but I cannot quite understand why it raises this warning. In my preamble I have the standard IEEEtran stuff, straight out of their template that comes with their zip file.

```
%\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this line out
                                                          % if you need a4paper
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}      % Use this line for a4
                                                          % paper

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              % This command is only
                                                          % needed if you want to
                                                          % use the \thanks command
\overrideIEEEmargins
```

I have the following stuff placed in (I think) the right place on my Ubuntu machine:

```
XXXXXXXXXX:/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/IEEE/IEEEtran$ ls
bare_adv.tex   bare_jrnl_compsoc.tex  bare_jrnl_transmag.tex  changelog.txt  IEEEtran.cls        README    tools
bare_conf.tex  bare_jrnl.tex          bibtex                  extras         IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf  testflow
```

Equally I have the ieeeconf.cls file in the same place as the .tex file that I am trying to compile as well.

Evidently I have mucked something up, any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a problem in some versions of the `ieeeconf.cls` file. On line 664 (on my version) you will find the following line:

```
\ProvidesClass{cssconf}[...]
```

Simply correct this to:

```
\ProvidesClass{ieeeconf}[...]
```

And the warning will not appear. Note though that the warning is actually completely benign.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the files you've got are a revision of the `ieeetran` document class made for the *IEEE Control Systems Society* by Pradeep Misra in 2004 which can be found at their websites, e.g. the [Conference Manuscript Management and Registration System](http://css.paperplaza.net/conferences/support/files/ieeeconf.cls) and [ITSC 2014](http://www.itsc2014.org/ieeeconf.cls).

The following lines produces the error:

```
\ProvidesClass{cssconf}[2004/1/15 revision V1.6b by Pradeep Misra]
%\ProvidesClass{IEEEtran}[2002/11/18 revision V1.6b by Michael Shell]
```

The document class name is renamed but not the filename itself.

The [original `ieeetran` document class](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran) is quite newer (2012/12/27 V1.8 by Michael Shell).You'll maybe try this one, too.

Comment: ieeeconf is kind of the preferred class for conferences. ieeetran conference option is problematic often.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies for taking this long to realize that there was this warning! The `.cls` file has been updated to reflect the correct class and the warning would not appear now. As noted by zelanix, the warning was completely benign.

Comment: Do you have two accounts?  Please visit the help page to get both accounts merged by stackexchange.